# ngx-barcode cannot be read randomly

Tags: angular, npm

I am currently using ngx-barcode with CODE128 format by Bryon Williams through this [website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-barcode). I am facing problem where some of the barcodes produced randomly cannot be read by scanner from analyzer. I would like to ask what might be the possible cause and solutions to this problem. I suspect is due to the low printing quality from the printer which is 203dpi. However, there might be other causes.  I have try the solution using from this [website](https://www.barcodefaq.com/knowledge-base/print-quality/). But still no progress as the unreadable issue happen randomly.

Other things that I had tried:

1. Resize the barcode font to 6pts.
2. Update the printer driver to support barcode font 128.

[image]

3. Reduce the width of the barcode

[image]

4. set the margin to default during printing to allow enough quiet zone.

[image]

Below is the example of my code snippet.

```
<ngx-barcode  class="barcode" [bc-valid]="isBarcodeValid"
 [bc-value]="setting.value" bc-element-type="svg" [bc-format]="setting.format" [bc-width]="setting.width" 
 [bc-height]="setting.height" [bc-display-value]="setting.displayValue" [bc-texalign]="setting.textAlign" 
 [bc-text-position]="textPosition" [bc-font-size]="setting.fontSize">
</ngx-barcode>
```

Printer driver using
[image]

Comment: What is your suggestions?

Comment: What are the configuration I can do to improve barcode print quality

Comment: Any feedback? Because the barcode readability issue is random. One batch of barcodes printed from same printer. Some barcode can read while other cannot .

Answer (score 1):

Facing the similar issue with code 128, Compared the picture shows little difference is causing the issue. It seems we should use some other library to generate the code [See the difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COXqH.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).